# How can I insert/update data in CosmosDB in an Azure function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

Suppose I have data in a file that represents a car dealers current (huge) inventory of unique (by some criterium) cars, and a new file is generated daily reflecting the inventory and price etc. of each car.

Parsing the file results in a list of `Car` objects.
The uniqueness of each car is represented in the `Car` object by some value, that would be the basis of a unique key in a regular rdbms setup.

I want the data in CosmosDB to be a queryable version of the data in the file. It should only hold data from the latest parsed file, and not data from previous files.

I have an Azure function that parses the file when it is uploaded to a blob storage, and inserts the parsed data into CosmosDB. However, this insertion will just grow the database over time with worthless data.

---

- **How can I UPSERT the parsed `Car` objects instead of always inserting them?**
- **Can the upsert be declared as part azure function instead of `ICollector<Car>`?**

I guess that CosmosDB could be used as an input to the Azure function and comparing the `Car` objects there with the ones in the file and updating/inserting when necessary, but I would prefer if CosmosDB or Azure function has a neat way of achieving this.

---

**The Azure function**:

```
[FunctionName("ParseCarsFromFile")]
public static void Run(
  [BlobTrigger("data", Connection = "StorageConnection")] TextReader textReader,
  [CosmosDB("data", "car", ConnectionStringSetting ="CosmosDb", CreateIfNotExists = true)] ICollector<Car> documentOutputBinding)
{
  var cars = CarsFileParser.Parse(textReader);

  foreach (var car in cars)
  {
      documentOutputBinding.Add(car);
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the document ID in Cosmos? Is it Car id or auto generated?

Comment: It is auto generated. Can it be the car id and still be og type Car?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upsert documents, change your `Car` class to have `id` property in it, and set it to unique car identifier.

`ICollector<Car>` should be ok for this case.

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work by creating a property called `id` (lower case) of type `string`.
I cannot get the latter to work, the id's are still guids out of my control.

Comment: @kasperhj I might have misinterpreted the examples then... I'll try that myself a bit later, removing this option from the answer until I prove it to work.