# Cosmos DB upsert from Azure Function - not updating, only inserting

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

When POSTing (from Postman), I end up with duplicate documents with the same "_id". Looking at the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52437913/azure-function-c-create-or-replace-document-in-cosmos-db-on-http-request) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49907405/how-can-i-insert-update-data-in-cosmosdb-in-an-azure-function), I'm wondering if my issue is that something is not set up correcly in my Cosmos DB instance?
Example:

> if I update my shape's color to orange, I get another
> document with the key of 1 but what I'm expecting is to see a single
> document with the key of 1 with a shape that has the color orange.

Function:

```
public static void Run(
  ILogger logger,
  [EventGridTrigger] EventGridEvent e,
  [CosmosDB(
      databaseName: "myDatabase",
      collectionName: "myCollection",
      ConnectionStringSetting = "COSMOS_CONNECTION_STRING")] out MyObject myObjectDocument
  )
  {
      logger.LogInformation("Event received {type} {subject}", e.EventType, e.Subject);

      myObjectDocument = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(e.Data.ToString());

      logger.LogInformation(myObjectDocument.some.thing);
}
```

Payload:

```
[
  {   
      "topic": "Topic",
      "id": "1",   
      "eventType": "EventType",   
      "subject": "Subject",   
      "eventTime": "2012-08-10T21:04:07+00:00",
      "data" : {
        "id" : 1,
        "effectiveDate" : "2020-10-18 15:00:00",
        "shape" : {
            "_id" : "1000",
            "color" : "green",
            "name" : "square"
        }
      },
       "dataVersion": "2.0",   
       "metadataVersion": "1"
  }
]
```

Edits:
Partition Key is "id"
Matias Quaranta's answer and comments did the trick. Note also the partition key must be a `string` and not an `int`

Comment: Please edit to provide more details. For example: Your Azure Function doesn't really do anything - not quite sure why it's included. And you haven't included any details on your upsert operation. Also, what is your collection's partition key?

Comment: I don't understand, I thought the Cosmos DB Output Binding handled the Upsert operation? Or is that only with Azure Functions 1.x? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54887882/azure-function-inserting-but-not-updating-cosmosdb) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52437913/azure-function-c-create-or-replace-document-in-cosmos-db-on-http-request) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb?tabs=csharp)

Comment: `_id` is the document identifier for Mongo. Cosmos DB's SQL API uses `id`. You are getting "duplicates" because you are relying on `_id` matching, which will never happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_id` is the document identifier for Mongo.

Cosmos DB SQL API uses `id`. You are getting "duplicates" because you are relying on matching the value of `_id`, and you can have millions of documents with the same `_id` but different `id`.

The document identity in SQL API is the value of `id` and the Partition Key. If your container has the Partition Key Definition as `/myPK` (for example, yours can be different) then the identity of the document is the value of `id` and `myPK` (or whichever is your Partition Key Definition) properties. When calling `Upsert` if a document with the same `id` and `myPK` values exists, it will be updated, if not, then a new document will be created with the body.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So my partition key is `_id` and what I'm reading is that I need to change it? If that is correct, would I be able to change it to `id` or will that lead to conflicts elsewhere?

Comment: If your partition key is `_id` then the identity of your documents are the value of `id` and `_id`. It sounds like based on your post, you really want to use `_id` as the identifier of the document. Maybe the best course of action is stop using `_id` in your documents and instead use `id` (because its what you are trying to do conceptually) and have the container have `/id` as partition key.

Comment: Changing the Partition Key Definition to `/id` but still sending the same payload that you are currently sending using `_id` as your document identifier won't solve your problem. The problem is conceptual in your design, you are conceptually trying to use `_id` to perform updates or creates and that works well in a Mongo database, but on Cosmos SQL API you need to use `id` to achieve the same goal. Your documents should contain `id` instead of `_id`, either the Event Grid data should have `id` or you could generate an `id` property that matches whatever is coming as `_id` in the Function.

Comment: I think I'm about there...I've changed my partition key (to `id`) and edited my payload. I'm now seeing Cosmos use the auto generated Id (guid) for the partition key instead of a value I specify in the payload. Is there something else I need to change or update?

Comment: The Cosmos DB SDK will autogenerate the `id` property if your document does not have it. This most likely mean your document does not have `id` property and it is still passing `_id`.

Comment: It looks like I had to pass my partition key as a `string` instead of an `code`. Thanks again for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

Items in cosmo DB can only be unique when Id and **partition key** are the same. If the partition key is different, but the Id is the same, the item is not unique.